# Combinatorics game problem

Tags: combinatorics

Two people, Alice and Ben, take turns removing marbles from a bag. The bag contains $1$ purple, $1$ orange, $4$ green, $6$ red and $2^8$ blue marbles. If Alice starts, at least one marble must be taken out on each turn and no more than one marble of the same color can be taken out on each turn, who removes the last marble? (whoever removes the last marble wins)

Answer (score 0):

Alice removes the last marble. Take the purple and the orange out first, then apply copycat strategy: take out whatever marble(s) Ben took on his last turn. This guarantees Alice to take the last marble since the parity of all colours marbles are even.

Comment: So Alice takes two at a time each time?

Comment: Not necessarily. She takes whatever amount Ben takes, and of the same color.